# PowerShell script to find log files more than 10 MB and send mail whenever a new file generated in that folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I need to find new files in a folder which are over 10 MB in size, and then send a mail with the name of the files.

The tricky part: Mail should be send when there is a new file arrives in the folder, so I have to always keep track and differentiate between the old file and new file.

Problem: I have written the following code and am not able to build the logic for mail. How can I identify the new file comes and trigger the mail?

```
$namearray = @()

$n = gci 'C:\Users\RF\local\ReuseLibrary\FamilySaveDirectory' | % {get-item $.FullName| ? { $.length -gt 10mb }}

foreach($a in $n) {

    $namearray += $a.name
}

$namearray

Send-MailMessage -To *@gmail.com -From '****@*.com' -Subject "Add User for $namearray NX License" -Body "Script execute $namearray successfully.." -SmtpServer 'mail.****.de'
```

Comment: Check out the powershell $FileSystemWatcher to check for file create/change/delete events   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, you can use the `FileSystemWatcher` object to monitor your filesystem. It got a little more tricky than just using the object, because you also need to be able to get the files which are already in the folder, not only the newly created ones.

Should the script really trigger the mail every time it has a new item in the `$namearray`? Maybe you'll get a flood of e-mails then.

It's better to use a function instead of a script to do your task because you have more flexibility, so you can check for only newly created files, and also for all files inside your folder.

Please try the function. I couldn't test it very well, because I don't have a folder where 10 MB large files get created all the time.

---

**Usage:**

To get *all files* (the wildcard * in the filter is important!):

```
Get-Files -filter '*.txt' -folder 'C:\yourfolder' -AllFiles
```

To monitor only new created files:

```
Get-Files -filter '*.txt' -folder 'C:\yourfolder' -NewFiles
```

**Function:**

Please edit the `Send-MailMessage` part so that you will receive the mail on your account.

```
function Get-Files() {
    param(
        [string]$filter,
        [string]$folder,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AllFiles')]
        [switch]$AllFiles,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NewFiles')]
        [switch]$NewFiles
    )

    # Preparing the Name array
    [string[]]$namearray = @()

    if(!$NewFiles.IsPresent) {
        # Getting all files which are already inside the
        # folder and more than 10 MB
        $files = gci $folder | % { get-item $_.FullName |
                               ? { $_.length -gt 10mb -and $_.Extension -like $filter} } |
                               % { $namearray += $_.FullName }
        # Send E-Mail
        $secondnamearray = $namearray | out-string
        Send-MailMessage -To '*@gmail.com' -From '****@*.com' -Subject "Add User for NameArray NX License" -Body $secondnamearray -SmtpServer 'mail.****.de'
        $namearray = ""
    }

    # Monitoring of the Files
    $monitoring = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $monitoring.Filter = $filter
    $monitoring.path = $folder
    $monitoring.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

    $event = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $monitoring -EventName Created -Action {

        # Checking for filesize
        $x = (get-item $eventArgs.FullPath).length / 10mb
        if ($x -ge 1) {
            Write-Host "New Item found: $($eventArgs.FullPath). Sending E-Mail!"
            $namearray += $eventArgs.FullPath
            $newnamearray = $namearray | out-string
            Send-MailMessage -To '*@gmail.com' -From '****@*.com' -Subject "Add User for NameArray NX License" -Body $newnamearray -SmtpServer 'mail.****.de'
            $namearray = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your prompt and such a detailed reply. I wish I could be as expert as you are. but thanks for such a master piece. I tried the same code but faced below error. May be I will try to fix the error. just for info below is the error message. For testing I have changed *.txt to *pdf as I am also not having such large log file. 

I have checked the path, it is correct but still the same issue. Give me some time I will do RCA and reply back. Thanks again.

Comment: ********error********
PS C:\Users\z003\Desktop\Performance> .\function.ps1
The term 'Get-Files' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\z003\Desktop\Performance\function.ps1:2 char:10
+ Get-Files <<<<  -filter '*.pdf' -folder 'C:\Users\z003\Desktop\Performance' -AllFiles
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Files:String) [], CommandNo
   tFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Sud you have to load the function first to use it. to load a function, you can just dot-source it like this: `. C:\yourpath\function.ps1` and then you can call `get-files`

Comment: I have created 2 .ps1 files 1 having the function & 1 having  both get – files command.
Then initially as you said I load the function as following 
. C:\Users\z003\Desktop\Performance\function.ps1
And then I call get – file as following.
.\With-function.ps1 
It is working perfectly. Whenever a new fils arrived in that folder mail is triggered. But my question here is here how to automate this thing, I have to leave keep open the PS cmd. How can I run this in background? May be I can create a service for this or I can schedule a task which will run each hour and trigger the mail

Comment: Create a new task in Task Scheduler triggering whenever you want. For Actions point it to "PowerShell.exe" and give it the command `-Command ". C:\Users\z003\Desktop\Performance\function.ps1"; Get-Files [[[params]]]` - just note if you are not running as yourself the System account will need access to the folder so might be better to put it in a folder like C:\Scripts or something.

Comment: Additionally if this is always going to be run with the same params I wouldn't even put it in a function, just hard code the variables (eg `$filter = *.*`), take out the Param block and Function bit, then you can run it with `& [filepath]` or `. [filepath]`, or in Task Scheduler with `-File [filepath]`.

Comment: @Sud if you want to trigger the scheduled task each hour, there is no need for file monitoring, then you would only need the "allfiles" part and yould delete everything from `#monitoring of the files` up to the last closing bracket `}`

Comment: @SimonS and Deadly-Bagel I have too late to reply but yeah the mess up was solved after your inputs. obliged and thanks.